# Stata Collapsing by first observation date when there are multiple date observations per ID

Tags: stata

I am working with a dataset that has purchases per date (called ItemNum) on multiple dates across 2800 individuals. Each Item is given its own line, so if an individual has purchased two items on a date, that date will appear twice. I don't care how many items were purchased on a date (with each date representing one trip), but rather the mean number of trips made across the 2800 individuals (For about 18230 lines of data). My data looks like this:

```
+---+----------+-------+---------------------- ---+
|ID |    Date  |ItemNum|        ItemDescript      |
| 1 |01/22/2010|   1   |Description of the item   |
| 1 |01/22/2010|   2   |Description of other item |
| 1 |07/19/2013|   1   |                          | 
| 2 |06/04/2012|   1   |                          |
| 2 |02/02/2013|   1   |                          |
| 2 |11/13/2013|   1   |                          |
+---+----------+-------+---------------------- ---+
```

In the above table, person 1 made two trips and three item purchases (because two dates are shown), person 2 made three trips. I am interested in the average number of trips across all people, but first I need to collapse it down to unique dates. So I know I need to `collapse` on the date, but when I do

```
collapse (mean) ItemNum (first) Date, by(ID)
```

it just takes the first date that the ID shows up, not the first occurrence of each unique date.

The next issue is that once it's collapsed, I need to take the mean of the count of the dates, not the date itself, which is also where I seem to be getting tripped up.

Comment: what are you trying to compute exactly? your post is rather confusing.

Comment: Your new question appears to call for another `collapse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or perhaps something like

```
clear
input ID str16 dt ItemNum
1 "01/22/2010"  1
1 "01/22/2010"  2
1 "07/19/2013"  1
end
generate Date = daily(dt,"MDY")
egen trip = tag(ID Date)
collapse (sum) trip, by(ID)
summarize trip

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
        trip |          1           2           .          2          2
```

if what you are looking for is found in "Mean" - a single number giving the average number of trips made by the 2800 individuals (1 individual with the limited sample data given).

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to do the following?

```
collapse (mean) ItemNum, by(ID Date) fast
```